# Multiple domains, Single database, 1 Parent/Master with all content, other domains/slaves with filtered content (based on "location" variable)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-field, conditional-content, content-restriction

Sorry if the `title` of this is not clear. Here's my scenario.

I want to create multiple sites (will use 3 as example) with the following content filtering.

www.main.com - serves all content
www.usa.com - serves content that is tagged or categorized as US-only content.
www.uk.com - serves content that is tagged or categorized as UK-only content.

From slave domains (e.g. uk.com), new posts MUST be forced to be UK-only. This leads me to not want to actually use Tag or Category as defined in WordPress. Perhaps use a Custom Field to manage this?

From master domain (i.e. main.com), new posts will be generalized as GLOBAL, and only the Administrator can reclassify to their local domain. This means that in a case where we don't have "canada.com", Canadian content will appear under main.com until such time when Canada.com is available and we can then reclassify it.

Or perhaps there's a free plugin that can help with content filtering?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Wordpress multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).  Sounds like that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't seem like what I need. Multisite don't share posts. They only share the folder structure and database but each side has its own tables in the database.  
  
Is there a way that you know that I can make them point to the same tables but pull different data?

Comment: There is a way to syndicate posts between sites, this plugin already has that functionality https://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/

Comment: This sounds like what I have been waiting for. Please make this into an answer and I will mark it as helpful.